# It is impossible to access the nested value in decoadable of generic type of struct in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, decodable

I want to know if i decode a data from api to generic type of model class, can i access in a nested value of generic type.
sorry for bad english.

GeneralResponse.swift - class for map data to object have data class which be a generic type

```
struct GeneralResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var code: String
    var dataResponse : T
}
```

Model.swift - model class for map in dataResponse field.

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var lname: String
}
```

APIManager.swift - map a data from api to object (send type of Model )

```
var myStruct = try! JSONDecoder().decode(GeneralResponse<T>.self, from: jsonData)
```

ViewController.swift - call a method in APIManager

```
APIManager.callRequest(url: "someURL", type: Model.self)
```

In this case, i want to access to "name" or "lname" but it can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below code

**APIManager.swift**

```
func callRequest<T:Decodable>(url: String,modelClass:T.Type,SuccessBlock:@escaping (T) -> Void){
    do {
        var myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(GeneralResponse<T>.self, from: Data())
        SuccessBlock(myStruct.dataResponse)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
callRequest(url:"someURL",modelClass: Model.self, SuccessBlock: { (response) in
     print(response.lname,response.name)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
do {
    let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(GeneralResponse<Model>.self, from: jsonData)
    print(myStruct.dataResponse.name)
    print(myStruct.dataResponse.lname)
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```